# Django_tables2: Add an edit and delete button next to each row

Tags: python, django

Let me preface this by saying that I'm new to django and python in general. I've read the Definitive Guide to Django and skimmed over most of the Python Essential Reference. That being said, I'm working on a standard application that works with models, their presentation and updating.

I've decided to go with django-tables2 for presenting sets of my data, but I can't seem to figure out how to add an edit and delete button which will take me to my `ModelForm` page for the chosen entity (in case of edit) or remove the selected entity (in case of delete, preferably with a pop-up). I also need to get back to the same place I pushed the button from (which I assume I'll need the `next` hidden field).

Anyway, I've been researching this for half a day now, and I don't know if I'm simply unlucky or the python community generally assumes a higher level of knowledge (at least from what I have). I'm pretty sure by now that I need to use the `TemplateColumn` but I have no idea what the `template_name` value.html is suppose to be, nor the purpose of `template_code`.

Could someone, with as much detail as possible, help me understand what it is I need to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some testing I found out that the template_name can be a reference to an .html containing a form with a hidden field that has the id of the entity displayed in the current row (using `{{ record.id }}`) and a submit input field.

I also set the form action attribute to `action="{{ request.path }}edit/"` to get to my desired view, though I still can't seem to access the `{{ request.path }}` in the hidden next field of the form, despite setting:

```
return render_to_response("azuriranje/stavka.html", {'form': form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and enabling the `'django.core.context_processors.request'` in the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` which is quite odd.

However, the original issue is resolved, though I can't understand why I have the value of `request.path` in my action, but not in my input field.